# How to convert Ilogger<one> to Ilogger<two> in Asp.Net.Core

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection

I have service with constructor One(Ilogger<One>) and second service Two(Ilogger<Two>). In some circumstances service One need to create instance of service Two and perform it.
Need to receive link to service locator, than link to logger service, than create instance of Logger from logger service factory or ...
What is a right way to convert Ilogger<One> to Ilogger<Two>?

Answer (score -1):

save link to loggerFactory

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    Environment = env;
    LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
}

public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public static IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; set; }
public static ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; }
```

and in class One

```
Startup.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<Two>();
```

Comment: Why not simply inject `ILoggerFactory` into your class and create instances of both loggers? Furthermore, `ILogger<T>` is simply a wrapper around `ILogger(string name)`. Even more so, why is one class logging for two?